# Como deixar desabilitado submit e habilitar após o preenchimento do input text ser maior que 10 reais?

Tags: javascript

```
<form>
 <input type="text">
 <input type="submit" disabled>
</form>
```

Gostaria de após preencher um valor por exemplo 10,00 ele habilitar e quando for valor menor de 12,50 ele desabilitar e observação (o campo é dinamico é um campo de total (soma de produtos), ele teria que ser automatico ao passar o valor já habilitar o submit)

Comment: Antes de tudo tem que resolver se é maior que 10 ou 12,50

Comment: Seria 12,50 desculpe!

Comment: complicou, rsrsrs, e se for igual?

Comment: Não é isso, você tem que postar o seu código. Observe que já fecharam a sua pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function EnableSend() {

var a = document.getElementById('idInp').value;
//troca virgula por ponto
a = a.replace(/\,/g,'.'); 

if (a>(10)){
  document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
}else{
  document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
}

}
```

```html
<form>
 <input id="idInp" type="text" onkeyup="EnableSend()">
 <input id="submit" type="submit" disabled>
</form>
```

Comment: Perfeito! Só que teria como ser com virgula pois meu script está somando os valores e aparecendo neste text com virgula

Comment: só fazer replace

Comment: Ixiii falou ingles cmg, kkkk não manjo do javascript mano poderia me da só mais essa luz

Comment: a = a.replace(/\,/g,'.');

Comment: Funcionou amigo, mais onde está o 10 poderia ficar 12,50?

Comment: Porque está puxando do banco de dados 12,50 aí ele vai direto pra li entendeu

Comment: só mudar no código, onde está 10 muda pro numero que quiser

Comment: Só que teria que ser com ponto né por exemplo 10.50 e não 10,50 correto?

Comment: onde tá 10 muda pra 12.5

Comment: certo e tem como colocar >= ?

Comment: no código é sim, javascript só faz comparação de numeros americanos, :-)

Comment: sim pode colocar >=

Comment: Funcionou! Só que o campo é dinamico a pessoa não digita nele ele apenas vai calculando conforme vão selecionando os produtos se for no manual digitando direto no text funciona mais dinamico não está indo!

Comment: Ai tem que mostar na pergunta como é esse dinamico ai pra gente poder estudar uma solução

Comment: Vou alterar aqui!

Comment: Alterei a pergunta!

Comment: @ Leo Caracciolo fiz outra postagem pode me ajudar? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/468396/como-fazer-submit-ser-habiliatado-ap%C3%B3s-o-valor-de-text-ser-maior-que-x-dinamicam