# como fazer submit ser habiliatado após o valor de text ser maior que x dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript

O código está funcionando se preencher o `input` diretamente e quando ele vai recebendo os valores dinamicamente ele não desabilita, só quando clico nele.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var tvalor = document.getElementById("tvalor");

tvalor.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');  
  const n0 = isNaN(tvalor.value.replace(',','.')) === false;
  const n1 = parseFloat(tvalor.value.replace(',','.'));
  const n2 = typeof n1 === 'number' && isFinite(n1);
  if (n0 && n1 && n2 && n1 >= 13) {
    btn.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
 <input type="text" id="tvalor">
 <input type="submit" id="btn" disabled>
</form>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloca na pergunta a função que inputa os valores dinamicamente, e lá que você precisa fazer acontecer.

Comment: São por checkbox ao clicar nos checkbox eles jogam o valor no total

Comment: Mostra pra gente.

Comment: Postei lá!.....

Comment: Poderia me ajudar amigo? só falta esse código para finalizar meu projeto!

Comment: Só falta mostrar como esses valores dinamicos são passados e recuperados aí no seu código.

Comment: coloquei uma opção com checkboxes na minha resposta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi o que disse sobre preenchimento dinâmico o que lhe falta é disparar o evento `keyup` após o preenchimento do `input`.

Para disparar um evento por código use o método [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) que dispara um evento, [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event), para o alvo do evento, [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventTarget), especificado, invocando os [EventListeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventListener) especificados, em uma ordem apropriada.

Seu exemplo eu modifiquei adicionando um botão `Preencher`(`btn2`) que preenche dinamicamente o input e dispara o evento `keyup` em `tvalor`:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var tvalor = document.getElementById("tvalor");

var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");

tvalor.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  const n0 = isNaN(tvalor.value.replace(',', '.')) === false;
  const n1 = parseFloat(tvalor.value.replace(',', '.'));
  const n2 = typeof n1 === 'number' && isFinite(n1);
  if (n0 && n1 && n2 && n1 >= 13) {
    btn.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
});

btn2.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  tvalor.value = "123";
  //Depois de preenchido dispara um evento no objeto.
  tvalor.dispatchEvent(new Event("keyup"));
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="tvalor">
  <input type="submit" id="btn" disabled>

  <input type="button" id="btn2" value="Preencher">
</form>
```

Comment: Acho que vai agora vou testar e já volto!

Comment: Funcionou amigo coloquei  tvalor.dispatchEvent(new Event("keyup")); no final do codigo do checkbox e foi....! Muito obrigado por dispor do seu tempo para me ajudar já estava doido aqui! Me salvou valeuuu fica na paz!

Comment: Só uma coisa que observei, no IE não funciona como faço ele funcionar?

Comment: @Rafa o Internet Explorer não suporta o constructor [`Event()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event), veja a tabela de compatibilidade. Para o IE deve se utilizar uma chamada já depreciada nos outros browsers [`Document.createEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent). O código fica assim: `var evento = document.createEvent('Event');  evento.initEvent('keyup', true, true); tvalor.dispatchEvent(evento);`

Comment: Beleza vou dá uma conferida! Obrigado, qualquer coisa volto aqui!

Answer (score 0):

Caso você use Jquery vc pode adicionar esse codico

```
    $('#btn').disabled=false;
```

caso não use adicione esse codigo:

```
    document.getElementById('btn').disabled =false
```

Edit:
esta complicado entender sua pergunta, mas pelo que vc falor o input tem que ser maio que x para desabilitar, como vc usa jquery vc pode inserir esse codigo por ultimo no script aonde vc faz o valor mudar

```
    <form>

 <input type="text" id="tvalor" value='13'>
 <input type="submit" id="btn" disabled>
</form>
<script>
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var tvalor = document.getElementById("tvalor");

let x =13;        
if(document.getElementById('tvalor').value !='' && document.getElementById('tvalor').value >=x){
        document.getElementById('btn').disabled =false

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Eu não sei como essa valor dinâmico é enviado/recuperado, portanto coloquei no código uma função que gera um valor randomico para testar o código. É só executar o código varias vezes que esse valor vai mudando e quando for maior que 13 desabilita o botão

```js
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

    /*######## valor dinamico ########## */
    function random(min, max) {
        return Math.round((Math.random() *( Math.abs(max - min))) + min);
    }
    let dinamico = (random(1, 26));
    /*################################## */
  
      if ( (dinamico !="") && (dinamico >= 13) ) {
      
        btn.removeAttribute('disabled');
        document.getElementById("tvalor").value = dinamico;
        
      }else{
      
        var tvalor = document.getElementById("tvalor");

        tvalor.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
          btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');  
          const n0 = isNaN(tvalor.value.replace(',','.')) === false;
          const n1 = parseFloat(tvalor.value.replace(',','.'));
          const n2 = typeof n1 === 'number' && isFinite(n1);
          if (n0 && n1 && n2 && n1 >= 13) {
            btn.removeAttribute('disabled');
          }
        });
      }
```

```html
    <form>
     <input type="text" id="tvalor">
     <input type="submit" id="btn" disabled>
    </form>
```

---

---

> **Com checkboxes seria algo assim**

```js
 //evento de alteração nos inputs checkbox
    $(":checkbox").on("change", function() {
      //altera o valor #total ao marcar/desmarcar os checkbox
      $("#total").val(function() {
        //declarar uma variável para manter a soma dos valores
        var sum = 0;
        var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        //Iteração para somar os valores das caixas de seleção marcadas
        $(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
          sum += ~~$(this).val();
          sumDiv=sum.toFixed(2);
          sumDiv = sumDiv.replace(/\./g,','); 
          $( "#totale" ).text("Valor total do pedido\n R$"+sumDiv);
          if (sum>=13){
            btn.removeAttribute('disabled');
          }else{
            btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled'); 
          }
        });
        return sum;
      });
    });      

    function sanduba1(){};
    function sanduba2(){};
    function cebola(){};
    function tomate(){};
    function milho(){};
    function molho(){};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="8" onclick="sanduba1()">
<label>Sanduiche Normal R$ 8,00</label>
<br>

<input type="checkbox" value="10" onclick="sanduba2()">
<label>Super sanduiche R$ 10,00</label>
<br>
      
<input type="checkbox"  value="2" onclick="cebola()">
<label>Cebola</label>
<br>

<input type="checkbox" value="3" onclick="tomate()">
<label>Tomate</label>
<br>

<input type="checkbox" value="4" onclick="milho()">
<label>Milho</label>
<br>

<input type="checkbox" value="2" onclick="molho()">
<label>molho</label>
<br>

<input id="total" style="display: none;">
<div id="totale"></div>
        
<input type="submit" id="btn" disabled>
```

Comment: Leo o código que o amigo postou ali em cima funcionou, mas obrigado, voc^^e está sempre me salvando kkk valeu mesmo!

Comment: Valor preenchido dinamicamente não é o mesmo que valor aleatório e também não é o mesmo que valor dinâmico. Valor preenchido dinamicamente é aquele preenchido por um automato(código) em tempo de execução independente da quantidade ser fixa ou aleatória..

Comment: @AugustoVasques, é o que ele disse no comentário - "São por checkbox ao clicar nos checkbox eles jogam o valor no total".